# ADF pipeline should be triggered after Formrecognizer analysis is completed

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-form-recognizer

I am calling AzureFormRecognizer from my Azure data factory 2 pipeline and sending a 200 page document

FormRecognizer takes around 5 mins to complete analysis and untill then status is "Running"

So I have added a Wait activity to wait for 5 mins and then I call GetAnalyze results by calling form recognizer api

**Question**
Is there any way to trigger ADF pipeline once Form recognizer completes its analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Execute pipeline activity** for this. Keep the **Formrecognizer activity** in a separate pipeline and **call that pipeline in main pipeline**.

Here for sample, I have used set variable actvity in the pipeline.
You can use your Formrecognizer activity in this.

[image]

Check on **wait on completion** so that it waits for the activity to get complete.

[image]

After Execute pipeline use your next activities which will be executed after the completion of FormRecognizer activity. For this demo I have used another set variable activity.

Or You can use another Execute pipeline after this if you want to trigger them in a separate pipeline.

Comment: Till form recognizer finishes analysis , do I have to pay pay for ADF ?

Comment: If you are running formrecognizer from ADF then you have to pay for it in the above approach.